# how to get object reference from other activity [android]

Tags: android, reference, android-asynctask, client-server

I have two major classes in my project. The first is for creating the connection between the client and the server. The second is for switching between activities.

first:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
public TCPClient mTcpClient;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    boolean flag = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("flag",false);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    Button menu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    if (flag == true)
    {
        //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        new connectTask().execute("");

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,Menu.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //  @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String message = editText.getText().toString();

            //clean the listView to 1 item
            if (message.equals("clean"))
            {
                arrayList.removeAll(arrayList);
                mList.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            }
            //add the text in the arrayList
            arrayList.add("c: " + message);

            //sends the message to the server
            if (mTcpClient != null) {
                mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
            }

            //refresh the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    //change Activity to live screen mode (live)
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });

}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            // @Override
            //print the message as an Item
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        arrayList.add(values[0]);
        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
        // from server was added to the list
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

the object `TCPClient mTcpClient` is the major factor in my app. I use it communicate with the server. In addition, even if I switch between activities it is still running properly so I still get info from server even though I am not in that activity.

second:

```
public class Menu extends Activity
{
    public MyActivity myActivity;
    public TCPClient mtcp;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, MyActivity myActivity) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);



    ImageView action = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    action.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            // here I would like to use mTcpClient object mentioned in the first class
            return false;
        }

    });
```

}

Basically what I need is a help on how to create in the second class reference to the object `mTcpClient` that is described in the first class.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong. If you want to use TcpClient class regardless of context it should NOT be related to first Activity. What you should do is to use singleton pattern:

```
class TcpClient {

    protected static TcpClient mInstance = null;

    public TcpClient() {
        // your init code...
    }

    public static TcpClient getInstance() {
        if( mInstance == null ) {
            mInstance = new TcpClient();
        }

    return mInstance;
    }

...
}
```

and then, whenever you want to use TcpClient you just do:

```
TcpClient client = TcpClient.getInstance();
```